# c, how to read operators issue, basics

Tags: c, operators

in "C Modern approach 2nd'ed " 
Are some exercises i can't understand the meaning. 
The result is 1, how do you read it ? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int i, j, k;

    i = 5;
    j = 0;
    k = -5;

    printf("%d", i && j || k);
    return (0);

}
```

Comment: `5 && 0` is 0, then `0 || -5` is 1.

Comment: do you know [`short-circuit concept`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) in C? Opps I notice that not applicable here!! still its good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operators ||(or) &&(and) named are bolean operators.

They return 0 or 1.

In order x&&y will return 1, it's necessary that x and y will be any number but 0. If at least one of them is equal to 0, it returns 0.

The operator || returns 1 if at least one of them is diffrent then 0, and 0 if they both qual to 0.

Answer (score 7):

```
 i && j || k
```

is equivalent to

```
 (5 && 0) || -5
```

equivalent to

```
0 || -5
```

equivalent to `1`.

Logical operators yield a value of `0` or `1`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan as no logical operator operand expression here has side-effects, it is not necessary for this question to know anything about short-circuits.

Comment: Ya I notice so delete my comment, post a comment to question instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is operated as

```
 ((i && j) || k)
```

so

```
(5 && 0)=0
```

and

```
  0||-5=1
```